# Remove and re add br tag at end of a HTML string

Tags: javascript, regex, string

I need some help working through some logic efficiently.  I need to remove all the break tags and newlines off of the end of this string and then add them back to the string after I am done with all my string manipulation.

```
str = "<br><br>My test string is here and <br> has some text in it.<br><br><br>\n\n<br>\n<br>";

// Code here that pops off all the break tags.

new_str = "<br><br>My test string is here and <br> has some text in it.";

// Break tags stored in a variable maybe?
end_tags = '<br><br><br>\n\n<br>\n<br>';

// More manipulation of the string.
final_str = "<br><br>My test string is here and <br> has..." + end_tags;
```

I know this could be done in regex gracefully, I am just hitting a wall making it work fast enough.

Comment: Please don't process HTML strings with regular expressions, doing so leaves you vulnerable to XSS attacks.

Comment: I don't see HTML parsing here. @PatrickRoberts

Comment: @revo removing `<br>` is not _parsing_, it's _processing_.

Comment: I had to interpret it as *parsing* otherwise it's not HTML processing. It's a simple text processing task which is what regex is made for. @PatrickRoberts

Answer (score 0):

You could simply use regex to solve your issue:

```
// Match all <br> and \n tags in the end
const matches = str.match(/^(.+?)((?:\<br\>|\n)+)$/)

// Matches = [Entire String, Stuff before the ending, all the end <br>s]
const [_, new_str, end_tags] = matches
```

#### ES2015 Way

```
// Match all <br> and \n tags in the end
var matches = str.match(/^(.+?)((?:\<br\>|\n)+)$/)

// Matches = [Entire String, Stuff before the ending, all the end <br>s]
var new_str = matches[1], end_tags = matches[2]
```

Answer (score 0):

Call `replace` method on `str` with a regex to do a match at the end:

```js
str = "<br><br>My test string is here and <br> has some text in it.<br>\n\n<br><br>";

new_str = str.replace(/(?:<br>|[\n\r])*$/, function(match) {
    end_tags = match;
    return '';
});

console.log(end_tags);
```

Comment: OP is doing the same. I shouldn't ask him why.

Comment: Keep in mind `<br/>` is valid, so is `<br />` `<br/ >`, and all kinds of other combinations, including the unlikely (but dangerous) `<br onmouseover="/*>*/alert('Hi')">`

Comment: Original poster isn't trying to validate data so no worry about a security risk at this level. I'm not sure if OP needs `<br />` too if yes he may modify the regex a little bit `<br ?\/?>` @PatrickRoberts

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan Lol, if we're trying to be pedantic then yes!

Comment: @AP i hate debugging so why not do it the (a bit more) pedantic way? `:)`

Comment: No, I didn't mean it. Are you suffering from ADHD? Question is clear enough. Re-read please. @RokoC.Buljan

Answer (score 0):

Edit: This is how I implemented this

```
var str = "<br><br>My test string is here and <br> has some text in it.<br><br><br>\n\n<br>\n<br>";

// replace line breaks with <span> to make things easier

var replaceStr = str.replace(/(\r\n|\r|\n)/g, '<span>');

// this get's the last line breaks or new lines at the end of the 
// string but also one extra string at the begining
// i.e it gets .<br><br><br>\n\n<br>\n<br> notice the (.) in front
var pattern = /(([^<br])(<br>|<span>)<br>.+|<span>.+|$).+$/gm;

var found = replaceStr.replace(pattern, function(match) {
  var firstChar = match.charAt(0);
  var remainder = match.substring(1);

  // add hello to remainder string

  return firstChar + ' add text, do stuff here ' + remainder;

});

// replace all spans to new line back

var finalResult = found.replace(/(<span>)/g, '\n');
```